# Get Twilio media with ColdFusion returns Unsupported Authorization Type

Tags: twilio-api

I am trying to access a media file from `Twilio` media file using Basic Authentication but I cannot get past the Unsupported Authorization Type error that it returns.

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>Basic {base64EncodedString}</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>EJY5E2NWV15KE9NF</RequestId>
    <HostId>ALdqQqofhIyUkZcVFga+W3dOiCenCTVr3LfZHg8G2AcX2fcuKtMJ1t4cF58cRNCnaAQs4mFG0dc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My setup looks like this:

```
<cfset acctSid = "ACeddxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<cfset acctToken = "6dd16xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<cfset msgSID = "MM365xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<cfset mediaSID = "MEg18xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<cfset urlStr = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#acctSid#/Messages/#msgSID#/Media/#mediaSID#">

<cfset authStr = toBase64("#acctSid#:#acctToken#")>
```

I have tried a couple of different HTTP calls both of which return the same thing.

```
<cfhttp method="get" result="result" url="#urlStr#" username="#acctSid#" password="#acctToken#">
```

and

```
<cfhttp method="get" result="result" url="#urlStr#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic #authStr#" >
</cfhttp>
```

Additionally, I have tried this as well.

```
<cfhttp method="get" result="result" url="#acctSid#:#acctToken#@#urlStr#">
```

Now, this actually works and returns an inline image; however, I do not want to settle on this solution due to the security implications.

I used Postman to make the same call and it works just fine. I have copied the base64 string that Postman generates and verified that it is indeed the same that is being passed by ColdFusion.